# Updating SQL Tables with external PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table in a database with a form, that shows the current values inside the table so they can be edited, as shown below. This requires a PHP/SQL "SELECT" script at the top of the page.

```
<form action="courseEdit.php" method="post" id="createCourse">
            <div id="wrapper1">
                <p> <?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['coursename'] ?> </p>

                <input id="location" type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['location'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Location"/> 

                <input id="time" type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['date'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Time"/> 

                <input id="minnumber" type="text" name="minnumber" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['minimumpeople'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Minimum Number of Students"/> 

                <input id="maxnumber" type="text" name="maxnumber" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['maximumpeople'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Maximum Number of Students"/> 

            </div>
            <div id="wrapper2">
                <textarea id="coursedesc" cols="50" rows="15" type="text" name="courseDesc" placeholder=" Course Description"><?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['description'] ?></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="objectiveone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['objective1'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Learning Objective One"/> 

             <input type="text" name="objectivetwo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['objective2'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Learning Objective Two"/> 

             <input type="text" name="objectivethree" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['objective3'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Learning Objective Three"/> 

             <input type="text" name="objectivefour" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['objective4'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Learning Objective Four"/> 

             <input type="text" name="objectivefive" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['editcourse']['objective5'] ?>" class="form-field" placeholder=" Learning Objective Five"/> 

            <input onclick="" type="submit" value="Register" class="button" id="createCourseBtn"/>

 </form>
```

On submit, the form refers to a separate page, where the form that they have just edited, will update the table's values that were displayed previously. That code is posted below, but as far as I can tell, once the submit button is clicked, it moves to "courseEdit.php" and forgets all the input values along the way.

```
 <?php
require("common.php");
$courseid = $_SESSION['editcourse']['courseID'];

$query = " 
            UPDATE courses
            SET 
                coursename = :coursename,
                location = :location, 
                date = :date,
                minimumpeople = :minnumber, 
                maximumpeople = :maxnumber, 
                description = :courseDesc,
                objective1 = :objectiveone,
                objective2 = :objectivetwo,
                objective3 = :objectivethree,
                objective4 = :objectivefour,
                objective5 = :objectivefive,
            WHERE
                courseID = $courseid
        "; 


        $query_params = array( 
            ':coursename' => $_POST['coursename'],
            ':location' => $_POST['location'], 
            ':date' => $_POST['date'],  
            ':minnumber' =>  $_POST['minnumber'],
            ':maxnumber' =>  $_POST['maxnumber'], 
            ':courseDesc' => $_POST['courseDesc'],
            ':objectiveone' => $_POST['objectiveone'],
            ':objectivetwo' => $_POST['objectivetwo'],
            ':objectivethree' => $_POST['objectivethree'],
            ':objectivefour' => $_POST['objectivefour'],
            ':objectivefive' => $_POST['objectivefive'],
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {   
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        header("Location: myprofile.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to registercourse.php");  

?>
```

Is there a way to put it on the initial page, and have it run only at submit? Or alternatively, have the values pass into the next php file so they can be updated properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean that you want to update the database using the first file i.e the file that contain your form?

Comment: yes, or any way of updating the table really

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function isset() at the top of your form to check if user submitted the form
code

```
   if(isset($_POST['location'])){  //use any valid field name
        $courseid = $_SESSION['editcourse']['courseID'];

        $query = " 
        UPDATE courses
        SET 
            coursename = :coursename,
            location = :location, 
            date = :date,
            minimumpeople = :minnumber, 
            maximumpeople = :maxnumber, 
            description = :courseDesc,
            objective1 = :objectiveone,
            objective2 = :objectivetwo,
            objective3 = :objectivethree,
            objective4 = :objectivefour,
            objective5 = :objectivefive,
        WHERE
            courseID = $courseid
    "; 


    $query_params = array( 
        ':coursename' => $_POST['coursename'],
        ':location' => $_POST['location'], 
        ':date' => $_POST['date'],  
        ':minnumber' =>  $_POST['minnumber'],
        ':maxnumber' =>  $_POST['maxnumber'], 
        ':courseDesc' => $_POST['courseDesc'],
        ':objectiveone' => $_POST['objectiveone'],
        ':objectivetwo' => $_POST['objectivetwo'],
        ':objectivethree' => $_POST['objectivethree'],
        ':objectivefour' => $_POST['objectivefour'],
        ':objectivefive' => $_POST['objectivefive'],
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    {   
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    //your can use meta tag to redirect user to another page
    ?>  
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=myprofile.php">
    <?php
   }
   ?>
   <!-- form details -->
```

remember to remove the action url in your form